# Using selenium VBA bringing the cell values from a dynamic web page table to excel cells

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium VBA and post googling have crated the below code in  order to bring the each cell value from a dynamic webpage using the selenium vba. I am getting error in receiving the web elements in a web_tr and web_td web elements

Have trying with this line:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = selenium.findElementByXPath("//table[@id='ctl00_cphContentBody_itemsTable']/tbody/tr['i']/td[1]").Text
```

I am getting a header line item first value only though it is under the loop.

Web_tr and web_td are web elements and receiving the web elements to these variables are the issue here. Kindly assist.

---

```
With ThisWorkbook
        .Sheets("UpfrontOrder#").Activate

       Set web_table = selenium.findElementsByXPath("//table[@id='ctl00_cphContentBody_itemsTable']/tbody")
       Set web_tr = web_table.findElementsByTagName("tr")   '***** the error pop-up gets in here****
       row_count = selenium.findElementsByXPath("//table[@id='ctl00_cphContentBody_itemsTable']/tbody/tr").Count

       For i = 1 To row_count
            Set web_td = web_tr.findElementsByTagName("td")
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = web_td(1).getText

            'ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = selenium.findElementByXPath("//table[@id='ctl00_cphContentBody_itemsTable']/tbody/tr['i']/td[1]").Text
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = selenium.findElementByXPath("//table[@id='ctl00_cphContentBody_itemsTable']/tbody/tr['i']/td[2]").Text
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value = selenium.findElementByXPath("//table[@id='ctl00_cphContentBody_itemsTable']/tbody/tr['i']/td[3]").Text
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value = selenium.findElementByXPath("//table[@id='ctl00_cphContentBody_itemsTable']/tbody/tr['i']/td[4]").Text
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 5).Value = selenium.findElementByXPath("//table[@id='ctl00_cphContentBody_itemsTable']/tbody/tr['i']/td[5]").Text
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value = selenium.findElementByXPath("//table[@id='ctl00_cphContentBody_itemsTable']/tbody/tr['i']/td[6]").Text
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 7).Value = selenium.findElementByXPath("//table[@id='ctl00_cphContentBody_itemsTable']/tbody/tr['i']/td[7]").Text

            'ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = web_td.findElementByXPath("td[1]").Text
            'ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = web_td(1).Text

        Next i
End With
```

Comment: Can you please include the error you are receiving? If im not wrong you are using Java?

Comment: The error is "Run-time error : Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: It hits in this line  "Set web_tr = web_table.findElementsByTagName("tr")"

Comment: No. I am using excel selenium VBA code..I just import "Dim selenium As New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver"

Comment: I guess you need to specify the index of the web_table. As per my knowledge, findelements of selenium will returns an array. So my understanding is web_table is an array of objects.So try Set web_tr = web_table[0].findElementsByTagName("tr")

Comment: I took this page as a reference "http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2014/06/how-to-handle-dynamic-web-table-in.html"

Comment: Sorry curretly that page is not showing anything. Please give a try with what i told

Comment: When I am about to set "Set web_tr = web_table[0].findElementsByTagName("tr")" system throws an immediate error "Compile error:

Expected: end of statement ".

Comment: sorry use web_table(0) instead of web_table[0]

Comment: "Set web_td = web_tr.findElementsByTagName("td")" Now again the same  "Run-time error : Object doesn't support this property or method"".

Comment: "Run-time error'13' : Type mismatch" when I am changing the code to Set web_td = web_tr(0).findElementsByTagName("td")

Comment: how did you declare web_tr and web_td? Can you add your entire code? in you question. Type mismatch is generally due to improper assignments like int to string etc

Comment: Do you really need to set the web_td? You are directly using xpath for each td in code. I guess uncommenting your 'ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value... and commneting web_td set will work.Please try

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with the VBA version of Selenium but from what I can tell, I see one issue that I think is causing the error you are getting. When you use `.findElements*` (plural), it will return a collection of elements instead of just a single element. Your first line (below) is using `.findElements()` but in the second line (below) is not specifying which element of the `web_table` collection to reference.

```
Set web_table = selenium.findElementsByXPath("//table[@id='ctl00_cphContentBody_itemsTable']/tbody")
Set web_tr = web_table.findElementsByTagName("tr")   '***** the error pop-up gets in here****
```

You can try to do one of two fixes...

1. Change `.findElements()` to `.findElement()` so that you only grab the first (and probably only?) table. If you only want the first one, this is the right way to fix this.
2. Add an index into the collection of elements from the first line, e.g. change `web_table.` to `web_table(1).` If you want a `TABLE` tag other than the first one, then add the correct reference.

   ```
   Set web_table = selenium.findElementsByXPath("//table[@id='ctl00_cphContentBody_itemsTable']/tbody")
   Set web_tr = web_table(1).findElementsByTagName("tr")
   add this _____________^^^
   ```

---

Additional Note:
I had another suggestion to simplify some of your code. In your `For i` loop you have hardcoded indexes 2-7 where I think you can easily use a loop. I updated the code below. This accomplishes two things...

1. It eliminates the repeated scraping of the page. In your original code, you are scraping one element at a time. In the code below, I grab a collection of `TD`s and then iterate through them. That way I'm only scraping the page once to get all the elements I care about and then processing that collection. It's more efficient.
2. Simplifies the code.

```
For i = 1 To row_count
    Set web_td = web_tr.findElementsByTagName("td")
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = web_td(1).getText
    Dim tds As New List
    Set tds = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = selenium.findElementByXPath("//table[@id='ctl00_cphContentBody_itemsTable']/tbody/tr['i']")
    For j = 2 To 7
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Value = tds(j).Text
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: I am getting an error pop up in this line now.. the same kind of

Comment: Set web_td = web_tr.findElementsByTagName("td")

Comment: Run time error '438'
Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: And one more thing as you suggested I could not able to find the new list "Dim tds As New List" instead I could able to figure related to list as collection only. I used "Dim tds As New Collection". Just FYI. Not sure whether any error may would occur as I am getting an error message b4 that line

Comment: Any particular reason why you removed the accepted flag on this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both of you.

The below code works well in finding the each cell values.

```
With ThisWorkbook
        .Sheets("UpfrontOrder#").Activate

       Set web_table = selenium.findElementByXPath("//table[@id='ctl00_cphContentBody_itemsTable']/tbody")
       Set web_tr = web_table.findElementsByTagName("tr")

       row_count = selenium.findElementsByXPath("//table[@id='ctl00_cphContentBody_itemsTable']/tbody/tr").Count

       For i = 0 To (row_count - 2)

            Set web_td = web_tr(i).findElementsByTagName("td")
            For j = 0 To 6
                   ActiveSheet.Cells((i + 1), (j + 1)).Value = web_td(j).Text
            Next j
        Next i
End With
```